# No module named 'kivy' even though it is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Ok so here's what happened I installed `kivy` using `pip` but it was giving some error which I searched for and it turned out `kivy` was not installed completely so I installed anaconda and opened its terminal there. I installed `kivy` and it showed requirements satisfied but when I ran my code below:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
 
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hello")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

It showed this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:/Work/Porjects/Face Detector/appk.py", line 1, in <module>
     import kivy
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

This is what my code looks like and the error:
[image]

Comment: Your Visual Studio is using `C:/Python38/python.exe`. Is that the anaconda python where you installed kivy?

Comment: it seems you have two Python installed - and you installed `kivy` in one Python but you run code with other Python. Every Python need own `kivy` and you may reconfigure VS to use Python which has already installed `kivy` or you have to install `kivy` using Python which you use in VS - ie `python -m pip install kivy`

Comment: @John Anderson it didnt work i did what u suggested